# Does python treat no return statement the exact same as return None?

Tags: python, return, python-internals

**Code:**

```
def foo():
    if condition:
        return some_value
    return None

def bar():
    if condition:
        return some_value
```

Both of these return None if condition is false, but do they vary in terms of computation time or anything else? Which one is generally preferred

Comment: I would expect them to result in identical bytecode, you can check it with `dis.dis(foo)` and `dis.dis(bar)`.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current versions of CPython, `return None` is exactly the same as not returning at all. Both are compiled into two bytecodes, a `LOAD_CONST` bytecode (to load `None`) and a `RETURN_VALUE` (to do the return).

You can see this by disassembling the two functions you've written, using the `dis` module:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (condition)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

  4           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (some_value)
              6 RETURN_VALUE

  5     >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis(bar)
  8           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (condition)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

 10           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (some_value)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
        >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

The only difference is that `bar` has fewer lines (indicated in the first column), since the implicit `return` doesn't correspond to any line in the source code.

The fact that they're identical is, however, an implementation detail. It's possible that other Python interpreters, perhaps even including other versions of CPython could produce different code for the two situations.

And even if the implementation is the same, an explicit `return None` may make it much more clear to somebody *reading* the code that you care about the return value. Relying upon the implicit return value suggests that you do not care about the return value, and that the function is primarily called for its side effects (e.g. printing something, or mutating some object in place).

And the person reading your code *might be you* in the future, after you've forgotten exactly how you programmed this function. Writing code that is clear about what it is doing is often even harder than writing code that compiles and runs correctly.

Comment: I'd even argue there are separate cases for `return` vs. `return None` beyond the distinction with no `return` at all; `return None` when the return value, even `None`, is expected to be used (usually having code paths with other return types), plain `return` for "exit before end of function, but no meaningful return" (with no other return types), no `return` at all for "exiting at end of function with no meaningful return" (with no other return types).